# Logging to STDOUT and a file with node/pino

Tags: node.js, logging, pinojs

I am sharing this as I struggled to get a pino logger to write to both STDOUT and a log file:

```
const dest = new stream.PassThrough();
dest.pipe(process.stdout);
dest.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/logs/file.log', { flags: 'a' }));
const logger = pino({ level: 'info' }, dest);
```

As this appears very low level, I wonder if this is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bit late but `pino-multi-stream` may be what you want. I followed [this section here](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-multi-stream#pinomsprettystream-prettyprint--prettifier-dest-) and it works for me in TypeScript for my purpose. You could try something like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const pinoms = require('pino-multi-stream')

const streams = [
  { stream: process.stdout },
  { stream: fs.createWriteStream('/logs/file.log', { flags: 'a' }) },
]

const logger = pino({ level: 'info' }, pinoms.multistream(streams));
```

Comment: From 10th June 2022, `pino-multi-stream` is now deprecated (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino-multi-stream) and the repo has been archived (https://github.com/pinojs/pino-multi-stream). Pino 7/8 support multiple streams so it is recommended to use the native support instead

Comment: There is also a performace hit using pino-multi-stream, don't use it if performance is important.

Answer (score 12):

if you are using pino 7+ you can just use the following:

```
const transport = pino.transport({
  targets: [
    {
      level: 'trace',
      target: 'pino/file',
      options: {
        destination: logPath,
      },
    },
    {
      level: 'trace',
      target: 'pino-pretty',
      options: {},
    },
  ],
});

export const log = pino(options, transport);
```

Comment: `pino-pretty` will prettify the logs that go to stdout which doesn't seem like what the OP wanted, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the logs written to file to be prettyfied, you might want to do something along those lines:

```js
const pino = require('pino')

const transport = pino.transport({
  targets: [
    {
      level: 'trace',
      target: 'pino/file',
      options: {
        destination: '/logs/file.log',
      },
    },
    {
      level: 'trace',
      target: 'pino/file',
      options: {
        destination: 1,
      },
    },
  ],
});

pino(transport)
```

`destination: 1` option represents STDOUT file descriptor, you can leave it out as `1` is a default value anyway.

Links to documentation:

- https://getpino.io/#/docs/transports?id=writing-to-a-custom-transport-amp-stdout
- https://getpino.io/#/docs/transports?id=pinofile